# Is Vector{Union{T, Missing}} double the size of Vector{T}?

Tags: arrays, julia

Is it right or there is a problem with `Base.summarysize` or ?

```
julia> x = rand(Int8, 100);

julia> Base.summarysize(x)
140

julia> x = allowmissing(x);

julia> Base.summarysize(x)
240
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It adds one single byte per element in this case:

> Julia can now also store "isbits Union" values inline in an Array, as opposed to requiring an indirection box. The optimization is accomplished by storing an extra "type tag array" of bytes, one byte per array element, alongside the bytes of the actual array data.
> https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/isbitsunionarrays/

For example consider the case with an `Int16`:

```
julia> x = rand(Int16, 100);

julia> Base.summarysize(x)
240

julia> x = allowmissing(x);

julia> Base.summarysize(x)
340
```

where
340 = (2+1)*100 + 40

- 2 bytes: the size of `Int16`
- 1 byte: extra-byte (the type tag)
- 40 bytes: meta-data (with the shape, offset...) independent of the array's size

Note that using less than a byte for the type tag would result that the elements are no longer aligned at bytes boundaries.